# D3js filter selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filtering, circle-pack

I am creating an interactive [bubble chart](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout) of [fortune 500](http://gomashup.com/cms/fortune_500_companies) data. I am trying to reduce a selection but can't figure out why it's not working as I expect.

```
var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    ...

d3.json("js/data/fortune2009.json", function(json) {

    var node = svg.data([json]).selectAll("g.node")
        .data(bubble.nodes); // filter here?

    node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "q" + color(d.Profit) + "-9"; });

    node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; })
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".3em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.Company.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});
```

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "children":[
    {
        "Year" : "2009",
        "Rank" : "1",
        "Revenue" : "442",
        "Profit" : "851.00",
        "Company" : "Exxon Mobil"
    },
    ....
}
```

I want to remove the parent node. I am trying to use a filter function like described [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter).

```
.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; })
```

But if i add my filter function where I initialize the `node` selection, either nothing happens or I get an error.

(The filter works when I apply it before appending text)

How do I solve this?

**UPDATE:** Here is a JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/B9w4N/8/ showing my problem.

[image]

Comment: At a glance I'd guess that you'd need to put your filter between `node.enter()` and `.append("g")`, but it'd take more time than I have to spare to get an example running so it'd help if you could put something working on JSFiddle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the array that the layout outputs:

```
var node = svg.data([fortune2009]).selectAll("g.node")
    .data(function(d) { 
        return bubble.nodes(d).filter(function(v) {
            return v.depth > 0;
        });
    });
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B9w4N/10/

Comment: Thank you @nautat. It solved my problem, but created another one. Why is the first circle acting weird when I interact with the chart?

Comment: You did something funny with reassigning data inside the interaction function. Also you want to use a key function to make sure a bubble corresponds to the same company, even after resorting of the data array. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B9w4N/11/

Answer (score 8):

You had the right idea. You just needed to apply the filter where the circles are created (in addition to where the text is created):

```
node
    .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; })
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });
```

Forked version on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SWcwn/)

Comment: Thank you @Richard. I actually tried this earlier, but it doesn't feel like the optimal solution, since a `<g class="node" transform="translate(300,300)"></g>` is created. I believe the filter could be avoided where the text is created if I just filter the selection earlier...

Comment: What should i do when i have multiple child inside node and for each node i want to append circle with node?

Comment: @AmitRana can you post a separate question, the comments of this one isn't a great medium for it. If you reply with a link to your question I'd be happy to have a go at answering it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353859/d3-js-append-element-to-node-depends-on-entity