# d3.js append element to node depends on entity

Tags: jquery, d3.js

i am working with d3.js force layout. not in json each node having property "extraData"and it's array. not all node having this property. i need to check when this property there add circles for each in "extraData" with node

i do some code with it

```
gStates = gStates.data(nodes);

    var gState = gStates.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr({
            "transform": function (d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")";
            },
            'class': 'node'
        })
        .call(drag);

    gState.append("circle")
        .attr({
            r: radius + 5,
            class: 'outer'
        });
gStates
        .filter(function(d) { if(d.extraData)return d; })
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d,i) { return 5+i; });
```

but it 's adding only one circle  any use full example or link will be great

when node having 3 element in "extraData" then node should display one big circle and 3 small circle surrounded it. just like text

here i create scenario in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmeetRana/DNXTS/2/) there is json at starting of javascript having two array inputList and outputList , i need to show circle for each input and output surround to main circle

Comment: Are you looking for a [bubble chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269)?

Comment: no no.. it's simple SVG adding circles. when circle have more child element it should added with smaller circle  , it's not any chart

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : it's same code that i am working with my last post question "zooming issue" so u can use same fiddle but there is no json and data is drag and drop so i need to modify it first.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the gStates selection

```
gStates.filter(function(d){ return d.extraData; })
```

make a shadow selection:

```
     .selectAll('.extraCircles')
```

Attach the extraData array to it

```
        .data(function(d){ return d.extraData; ).enter()
```

and append a circle

```
      .append('circle')
        .attr("r", function(d,i) { return 5+i; });
```

Comment: Still it's only one circle , i think gStates.filter is alwase returning one data only

Comment: Could you post a js.fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AmeetRana/DNXTS/2/   i need to show circles for each inputList element and outputList element with main node circla